# how to fix django staticfiles page not found in heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku

static files are not working in production in Heroku.but when in development it works, since yesterday I couldn't solve it. please help me.

settings.py

```
  STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticfiles')
  STATIC_URL = '/static/'


  MEDIA_URL='/media/'
  MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

  CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK='uni_form'

  LOGIN_URL='/login'

  LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/app'
  LOGOUT_REDIRECT='/'
```

Comment: _Specifically_, what does "not working" mean? Have you read about hosting static files on Heroku? Are you using `django-heroku`? Whitenoise? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

During development, if you use django.contrib.staticfiles, this will be done automatically by runserver when DEBUG is set to True (see django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve()).

This method is grossly inefficient and probably insecure, so it is unsuitable for production.

See Deploying static files for proper strategies to serve static files in production environments.
See [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/) and [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets#whitenoise)